# What's wrong with installing scipy via pip, py39 under FreeBSD 13.1?

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, virtualenv, freebsd

I'm triyng to install scipy via pip in an virtual environment but it ends with an error.
 `$ uname -a FreeBSD BSD-13 13.1-RELEASE-p3 FreeBSD 13.1-RELEASE-p3 GENERIC amd64`

Venv is with python 3.9

What I do:
`(env)$ pip install scipy`

What I get:
`  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.`

From output:

```
 (env) $ pip install scipy                                                                                                                                 
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error                                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                                            
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.                                                                                                                                           
  │ exit code: 1                                                                                                                                                                                             
  ╰─> [1115 lines of output]                                                                                                                                                                                
      The Meson build system    
      Version: 1.1.1                                                                                                                                                                                         
      Source dir: /tmp/pip-install-5z2e6tci/scipy_ad2046d2ded14815af222ec7dbe3dd66                                                                                                                           
      Build dir: /tmp/pip-install-5z2e6tci/scipy_ad2046d2ded14815af222ec7dbe3dd66/.mesonpy-rx7e0be7/build                                                                                                    
      Build type: native build                                                                                                                                                                               
      Project name: SciPy                                                                                                                                                                                    
      Project version: 1.10.1                                                                                                                                                                                
      C compiler for the host machine: cc (clang 13.0.0 "FreeBSD clang version 13.0.0 (git@github.com:llvm/llvm-project.git llvmorg-13.0.0-0-gd7b669b3a303)")                                                
      C linker for the host machine: cc ld.lld 13.0.0                                                                                                                                                        
      C++ compiler for the host machine: c++ (clang 13.0.0 "FreeBSD clang version 13.0.0 (git@github.com:llvm/llvm-project.git llvmorg-13.0.0-0-gd7b669b3a303)")                                             
      C++ linker for the host machine: c++ ld.lld 13.0.0                                                                                                                                                     
      Cython compiler for the host machine: cython (cython 0.29.35)                                                                                                                                          
      Host machine cpu family: x86_64                                                                                                                                                                        
      Host machine cpu: x86_64                                                                                                                                                                               
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-unused-but-set-variable: YES                                                                                                                                    
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-unused-function: YES                                                                                                                                            
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-conversion: YES                                                                                                                                                 
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-misleading-indentation: YES                                                                                                                                     
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-incompatible-pointer-types: YES                                                                                                                                 
      Library m found: YES                                                                                                                                                                                   
      Fortran compiler for the host machine: gfortran (gcc 12.2.0 "GNU Fortran (FreeBSD Ports Collection) 12.2.0")                                                                                           
      Fortran linker for the host machine: gfortran ld.bfd 2.40                                                                                                                                              
      Compiler for Fortran supports arguments -Wno-conversion: YES                                                                                                                                           
      Checking if "-Wl,--version-script" : links: YES                                                                                                                                                        
      Program cython found: YES (/tmp/pip-build-env-cfphp0hs/overlay/bin/cython)                                                                                                                             
      Program python found: YES (/usr/home/argkh/PyVenv/env/bin/python3)                                                                                                                                     
      Found pkg-config: /usr/local/bin/pkg-config (1.8.1)                                                                                                                                                    
      Program pythran found: YES (/tmp/pip-build-env-cfphp0hs/overlay/bin/pythran)                                                                                                                           
      Run-time dependency threads found: YES                                                                                                                                                                 
      Library npymath found: YES                                                                                                                                                                             
      Library npyrandom found: YES                                                                                                                                                                           
      Run-time dependency openblas found: YES 0.3.20                                                                                                                                                         
      Dependency openblas found: YES 0.3.20 (cached)                                                                                                                                                         
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-maybe-uninitialized: NO                                                                                                                                         
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-discarded-qualifiers: NO                                                                                                                                        
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-empty-body: YES                                                                                                                                                 
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-implicit-function-declaration: YES                                                                                                                              
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-parentheses: YES                                                                                                                                                
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-switch: YES                                                                                                                                                     
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-unused-label: YES                                                                                                                                               
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-unused-variable: YES                                                                                                                                            
      Compiler for C++ supports arguments -Wno-cpp: YES                                                                                                                                                      
      Compiler for C++ supports arguments -Wno-deprecated-declarations: YES                                                                                                                                  
      Compiler for C++ supports arguments -Wno-class-memaccess: NO                                                                                                                                           
      Compiler for C++ supports arguments -Wno-format-truncation: NO                                                                                                                                         
      Compiler for C++ supports arguments -Wno-non-virtual-dtor: YES                                                                                                                                         
      Compiler for C++ supports arguments -Wno-sign-compare: YES                                                                                                                                             
      Compiler for C++ supports arguments -Wno-switch: YES                                                                                                                                                   
      Compiler for C++ supports arguments -Wno-terminate: NO                                                                                                                                                 
      Compiler for C++ supports arguments -Wno-unused-but-set-variable: YES                                                                                                                                  
      Compiler for C++ supports arguments -Wno-unused-function: YES     
      Compiler for C++ supports arguments -Wno-unused-local-typedefs: YES                                                                                                                                    
      Compiler for C++ supports arguments -Wno-unused-variable: YES                                                                                                                                          
      Compiler for C++ supports arguments -Wno-int-in-bool-context: YES                                                                                                                                      
      Compiler for Fortran supports arguments -Wno-argument-mismatch: YES                                                                                                                                    
      Compiler for Fortran supports arguments -Wno-conversion: YES (cached)                                                                                                                                  
      Compiler for Fortran supports arguments -Wno-intrinsic-shadow: YES                                                                                                                                     
      Compiler for Fortran supports arguments -Wno-maybe-uninitialized: YES                                                                                                                                  
      Compiler for Fortran supports arguments -Wno-surprising: YES                                                                                                                                           
      Compiler for Fortran supports arguments -Wno-uninitialized: YES                                                                                                                                        
      Compiler for Fortran supports arguments -Wno-unused-dummy-argument: YES                                                                                                                                
      Compiler for Fortran supports arguments -Wno-unused-label: YES                                                                                                                                         
      Compiler for Fortran supports arguments -Wno-unused-variable: YES                                                                                                                                      
      Compiler for Fortran supports arguments -Wno-tabs: YES                                                                                                                                                 
      Compiler for Fortran supports arguments -Wno-argument-mismatch: YES (cached)                                                                                                                           
      Compiler for Fortran supports arguments -Wno-conversion: YES (cached)                                                                                                                                  
      Compiler for Fortran supports arguments -Wno-maybe-uninitialized: YES (cached)                                                                                                                         
      Compiler for Fortran supports arguments -Wno-unused-dummy-argument: YES (cached)                                                                                                                       
      Compiler for Fortran supports arguments -Wno-unused-label: YES (cached)                                                                                                                                
      Compiler for Fortran supports arguments -Wno-unused-variable: YES (cached)                                                                                                                             
      Compiler for Fortran supports arguments -Wno-tabs: YES (cached)                                                                                                                                        
      Checking if "Check atomic builtins without -latomic" : links: YES                                                                                                                                      
      Configuring __config__.py using configuration                                                                                                                                                          
      Checking for function "open_memstream" : YES                                                                                                                                                           
      Configuring messagestream_config.h using configuration                                                                                                                                                 
      Compiler for Fortran supports arguments -w: YES                                                                                                                                                        
      Checking for size of "void*" : 8                                                                                                                                                                       
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-unused-variable: YES (cached)                                                                                                                                   
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-parentheses: YES (cached)                                                                                                                                       
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-unused-label: YES (cached)                                                                                                                                      
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-implicit-function-declaration: YES (cached)                                                                                                                     
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-switch: YES (cached)                                                                                                                                            
      Compiler for Fortran supports arguments -w: YES (cached)                                                                                                                                               
      Checking for size of "void*" : 8 (cached)                                                                                                                                                              
      Build targets in project: 252                                                                                                                                                                          
      NOTICE: Future-deprecated features used:                                                                                                                                                               
       * 1.1.0: {'"boolean option" keyword argument "value" of type str'}                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                            
      SciPy 1.10.1                                                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                                            
        User defined options                                                                                                                                                                                 
          Native files: /tmp/pip-install-5z2e6tci/scipy_ad2046d2ded14815af222ec7dbe3dd66/.mesonpy-native-file.ini                                                                                            
          debug       : false                                                                                                                                                                                
          optimization: 2                                                                                                                                                                                    
          prefix      : /usr/local                                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                                            
      Found ninja-1.11.1.git.kitware.jobserver-1 at /tmp/pip-build-env-cfphp0hs/normal/bin/ninja                                                                                                             
     
......................................................

      [819/1619] Linking target scipy/stats/_qmc_cy.cpython-39.so                                                                                                                                            
      [820/1619] Compiling C++ object scipy/stats/_stats_pythran.cpython-39.so.p/meson-generated_..__stats_pythran.cpp.o                                                                                     
      FAILED: scipy/stats/_stats_pythran.cpython-39.so.p/meson-generated_..__stats_pythran.cpp.o                                                                                                             
      c++ -Iscipy/stats/_stats_pythran.cpython-39.so.p -Iscipy/stats -I../../scipy/stats -I/tmp/pip-build-env-cfphp0hs/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pythran -I/tmp/pip-buil                           d-env-cfphp0hs/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fcolor-diagnostics -D_FILE_O
FFSET_BITS=64 -Wall -Winvalid-pch -std=c++14 -O2 -fPIC -DENABLE_PYTHON_MODULE -D__PYTHRAN__=3 -DPYTHRAN_BLAS_NONE -Wno-cpp -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-int-in-bool-context -MD -MQ scipy/stats/_stats_pythran.cpython-39.so.p/meson-generated_..__stats_pythran.cpp.o -MF scipy/stats/_stats_pythran.cpython-39.so.p/meson-generated_..__stats_pythran.cpp.o.d -o scipy/stats/_stats_pythran.cpython-39.so.p/meson-generated_..__stats_pythran.cpp.o -c scipy/stats/_stats_pythran.cpp
      In file included from scipy/stats/_stats_pythran.cpp:34:
      In file included from /tmp/pip-build-env-cfphp0hs/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pythran/pythonic/include/numpy/ceil.hpp:8:
      In file included from /tmp/pip-build-env-cfphp0hs/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pythran/xsimd/xsimd.hpp:55:
      /tmp/pip-build-env-cfphp0hs/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pythran/xsimd/arch/xsimd_scalar.hpp:447:16: error: no member named 'exp10f' in the global namespace; did you mean 'exp10'?
              return ::exp10f(x);
                     ^~~~~~~~
                     exp10
      /tmp/pip-build-env-cfphp0hs/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pythran/xsimd/arch/xsimd_scalar.hpp:445:18: note: 'exp10' declared here
          inline float exp10(const float& x) noexcept
                       ^
      /tmp/pip-build-env-cfphp0hs/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pythran/xsimd/arch/xsimd_scalar.hpp:451:16: error: no member named 'exp10' in the global namespace; did you mean simply 'exp10'?
              return ::exp10(x);
                     ^~~~~~~
                     exp10
      /tmp/pip-build-env-cfphp0hs/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pythran/xsimd/arch/xsimd_scalar.hpp:449:19: note: 'exp10' declared here
          inline double exp10(const double& x) noexcept
                        ^
      2 errors generated.
      [821/1619] Generating 'scipy/stats/_boost/binom_ufunc.cpython-39.so.p/binom_ufunc.cpp'.
      [822/1619] Compiling C object scipy/stats/_sobol.cpython-39.so.p/meson-generated__sobol.c.o
      [823/1619] Compiling C object scipy/stats/_stats.cpython-39.so.p/meson-generated__stats.c.o
      [824/1619] Compiling C++ object scipy/sparse/sparsetools/_sparsetools.cpython-39.so.p/csr.cxx.o
      [825/1619] Compiling C++ object scipy/sparse/sparsetools/_sparsetools.cpython-39.so.p/bsr.cxx.o
      ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
      INFO: autodetecting backend as ninja
      INFO: calculating backend command to run: /tmp/pip-build-env-cfphp0hs/normal/bin/ninja
      + meson setup --prefix=/usr/local /tmp/pip-install-5z2e6tci/scipy_ad2046d2ded14815af222ec7dbe3dd66 /tmp/pip-install-5z2e6tci/scipy_ad2046d2ded14815af222ec7dbe3dd66/.mesonpy-rx7e0be7/build --native-file=/tmp/pip-install-5z2e6tci/scipy_ad2046d2ded14815af222ec7dbe3dd66/.mesonpy-native-file.ini -Ddebug=false -Doptimization=2
      + meson compile
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details
```

Answer (score 2):

Like it is said here:

```
In file included from /tmp/pip-build-env-cfphp0hs/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pythran/xsimd/xsimd.hpp:55:
      /tmp/pip-build-env-cfphp0hs/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pythran/xsimd/arch/xsimd_scalar.hpp:447:16: error: no member named 'exp10f' in the global namespace; did you mean 'exp10'?
              return ::exp10f(x);
                     ^~~~~~~~
                     exp10
```

`::exp10f` is not found ; so, it is related to `pythran`, which is required by `scipy` ; this bug has a workaround here :
[FreeBSD-13.1-pythran-issues-2070](https://github.com/serge-sans-paille/pythran/issues/2070)

Or you could try to install it through the ports collection in `science/py-scipy`, which is better than `pip` because any bug found have their patches already. What you get with `pip` is compiling from the the source tree which could lead to some bug because it is generally made (or designed) under Linux.

Comment: Thank you, I had installed pythran 0.13.1, but scipy install still breaks with similar errors.